# Convex hulls of compact sets

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, gn.general-topology, convex-polytopes, hilbert-spaces

Let $A$ be a compact set in a separable Hilbert space $H$, and let $\bar A$ denote its convex hull. Is $\bar A$ compact?

Comment: Not necessarily. Proof by google, counterexample [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&pg=PA185).

Comment: Via Theorem 5.35 on that page, the answer is "yes" if one replaces "convex hull" with "closed convex hull".

Comment: (note: that theorem requires that $H$ be locally convex and completely metrizable, which is satisfied for a Hilbert space $H$. The assumption of separability is not necessary)

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/6627/convex-hull-in-cat0 this related question is purportedly open

Comment: In any locally convex space $E$, the closed convex hull of a precompact set $X$ is precompact (see Schaefer's Top. Vect. Sp., Chapter II, Section 4.3). It follows that if $E$ is quasi-complete (every closed bounded set is complete - automatically true if $E$ is complete), then the closed convex hull of $X$ is compact, being precompact and complete.