# Are sequences in $\ell^1(\mathbb N_0)$ converging uniformly on convex weakly compact subsets of $c_0(\mathbb N_0)$ norm convergent?

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I think the question as expressed in the title should be clear. I do not know whether there is a known "characterization" of the weakly compact convex sets in $c_0(\mathbb N_0)$ but testing examples has lead me to conjecture that sequences in $\ell^1(\mathbb N_0)$ converging to zero uniformly on these sets also converge to zero in the norm topology. Is this conjecture correct/know/well-know/is there an explicit reference?

Comment: Check out Schur's property in Banach space theory.

Comment: @bathalf15320 To use it, one should be able to prove that convergence on convex weakly compact sets in $c_0$ implies convergence at vectors in $\ell^{\,+\infty}$. Do you have any idea for this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you consider convex sets only? Since the closed convex hull of a weakly compact set is again weakly compact, it doesn't seem to make a difference if we just drop "convex".

Comment: @JochenGlueck I am considering on $\ell^1$ the Mackey topology of the pair $(c_0,\ell^1)$ and I ultimately want to know whether there are more sequentially continuous than continuous linear forms on $\ell^1$ with this topology. The "convex" comes from the definition once the "circled" there is trivially dropped. What is the precise argument for dropping "convex"?

Comment: Jochen Glueck is right, this is a theorem of **Krein** (it holds in all quasi-complete locally convex spaces). The topology of uniform convergence on all weakly compact avsolutely convex sets is the **Mackey topology** on $\ell^1$ for the dual pair $\langle c_0,\ell^1\rangle$.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Do you intend to say that $c_0$ with the weak topology is quasi-complete? Its unit ball is not even sequentially complete, or am I wrong?

Comment: No, of course not (weak quasi-completeness is equivalent to semi-reflexivity). The theorem of Krein applies to the Banach space $c_0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is yes.

*Proof.* Assume to the contrary that a sequence $(x_n)$ in $\ell^1$ converges, say to $0$, uniformly on convex weakly compact subsets of $c_0$, but is not norm convergent and hence not norm convergent to $0$.

Note that the sequence even converges uniformly on all weakly compact subsets of $c_0$, be they convex or not (since [the closed convex hull of a weakly compact set is again weakly compact](https://mathoverflow.net/a/218164/102946)). So if we construct a sequence $(y_n)$ in $c_0$ that converges weakly to $0$ but such that $\langle y_n, x_n \rangle \not\to 0$, then we have a contradiction.

After replacing $(x_n)$ with a subsequence we may assume that $\|x_n\| \ge \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$ and all $n$.
Moreover, since $(x_n)$ converges, in particular, weakly to $0$, it also converges pointswise to $0$. So after replacing $(x_n)$ with yet another subsequence we may assume that, for all $n$, we have $\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} |x_n(k)| < \varepsilon/3$. Hence, there exist numbers $N_n \ge n$ such that $\sum_{k=n}^{N_n} |x_n(k)| \ge \varepsilon / 3$ for each $n$.

Now simply choose $y_n(k)$ to be zero for $k$ outside the set $\{n,\dots, N_n\}$ and to be the complex conjugate of the (complex) sign of $x_n(k)$ for $k$ inside this set. Then we have $\langle y_n, x_n \rangle \ge \varepsilon / 3$ for each $n$. Moreover, the sequence $(y_n)$ in $c_0$ is bounded and converges pointwise to $0$; hence, it also converges weakly to $0$.

Comment: Great! The *closed convex hull of a weakly compact set is weakly compact* was the most important observation that was missing in my head.

Answer (score 3):

*Please take this post as an appendix to Jochen Glueck's answer.* Let $X$ be a Banach space and $(f_n)$ be a sequence in $X^*$. It is fairly routine to show the equivalence of the following.

1. $\sup\{|f_n(x)|:x\in A\}\to 0$ for every weakly compact $A\subseteq X$.
2. $f_n(x_n)\to 0$ for every weakly null sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$.
3. $f_n(x_n)\to 0$ for every weakly Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$.
4. $\sup\{|f_n(x)|:x\in A\}\to 0$ for every weakly precompact     $A\subseteq X$.

Now suppose, in addition, that $X$ does not contain an isomorphic copy of $\ell^1$. Then, the unit ball $B$ of $X$ is weakly precompact. Thus, (1-4) above is also equivalent to

- $\|f_n\| = \sup\{|f_n(x)|:x\in B\}\to 0$.

Clearly, $c_0$ is a Banach space that doesn't contain an isomorphic copy of $\ell^1$.

Comment: The unit ball of **every** normed space is weakly precompact -- so what is the point about the containment of $\ell^1$?

Comment: @JochenWengenroth For example, the unit ball of $\ell^1$ is not weakly precompact. The standart basis $(e_n)$ of $\ell^1$, as a sequence, doesn't have a weakly Cauchy subsequence in $\ell^1$.

Comment: @OnurOktay In a precompact/totally bounded uniform space every net, in particular every sequence, has a Cauchy sub*net* but need not have a Cauchy sub*sequence*. The concept of subnet is more involved than that of subsequence since one may have to consider another directed (index)set. Btw., what is the "fairly routine" argument (apart from Jochen Glueck's answer) to show that any of 1,2 or 3 implies 4?

Comment: I use the term "weakly precompact" as it is customary to use in Banach space terminology: "A subset of a Banach space $A$ is weakly precompact if every sequence in $A$ has a weakly Cauchy subsequence". Perhaps this usage caused ambiguity. The well-known theorem of Rosenthal provides that if $A$ contains no sequence that spans an isomorphic copy of $\ell^1$, then $A$ is weakly precompact.

Comment: It is also well-known that the unit ball $B^{**}$ of $X^{**}$ is weak$^*$ compact by Banach-Alaoglu theorem, and the unit ball $B$ of $X$ is weak$^*$ dense in $B^{**}$ by Goldstine's theorem. Clearly the restriction of the weak$^*$ topology to $B$ is the same as the weak topology on $B$. Thus, it's true that every net in $B$ has weak$^*$ limit points in $B^{**}$, and every  $x^{**}\in B^{**}$ is a weak$^*$  limit of a net in $B$.

Comment: @OnurOktay So, if I have understood correctly, the core in your argument is an appeal to the Rosenthal theorem. It is unfortunate that in the "Banach space theory circle" the terminology does not always coincide with that in general topology. I would have said e.g. "sequentially weakly precompact".

Comment: That Banach spacers abuse standard topological terminology is very strange -- if weakly precompact means precompact in the weak topology even every bounded set of any locally convex topological vector space is weakly precompact.

Comment: @TaQ Sir, as much as I agree with you, I can't see myself as a revolutionary to alter the common terminology - I am a simple lifelong student. In any case, as an ardent follower of Carlo Cipolla and his treatise *"Allegro ma non Troppo"*, I believe that my humble opinion will neither increase nor decrease the TSM ratio of the world.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth Could your point perhaps be the reason to shorten "weakly sequentially precompact" to "weakly precompact"? Similarly, a Banach algebra is said to be semisimple if it is, in fact, Jacobson semisimple. A semisimple (in the algeraic sense) Banach algebra is always isomorphic to a finite direct sum of matrix algebras, which is perhaps considered to be of triviality.